# How to use f:translate within additionalAttributes of f:form.textfield

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to insert a translated placeholder within my f:form.textfield

```
<f:form.textfield name="search[sword]" value="{sword}" class="form-element" additionalAttributes="{placeholder: '<f:translate key="placeholder" />'}"/>
```

The output works if I replace the placeholder with normal text. I can output my translated placeholder elsewhere as well, but not within the attribut of the f:form.textfield.

I can not spot a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use inline sysntax, for additional attributes like:

```
        <f:form.textfield name="search[sword]" value="{sword}" class="form-element" additionalAttributes="{placeholder: '{f:translate(key:\'placeholder\')}'}"/>
```

With TYPO3 CMS >= 6.2 you can use placeholder directly as argument for textfields:

```
        <f:form.textfield name="search[sword]" value="{sword}" class="form-element" placeholder="{f:translate(key:'placeholder')}"/>
```